# What is theMost compressible material commonly found?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I'd like to know which solid material is highly compressable .
I think plastic is widely available and quite compressable.

What is something better?

Comment: "What is the most compressible material commonly found?"

You have to search for the [Bulk Modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) for the materials that interest you. The comprehensibility is **1/Bulk Modulus**. The smaller the Bulk modulus the higher the comprehensibility.

Here you have the [Bulk Modulus of the elements in the periodic table](http://www.periodictable.com/Properties/A/BulkModulus.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Caesium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium)

[image]

From: ["Physics 1942 – 1962: Including Presentation Speeches and Laureates' Biographies" by Yong Zhou](https://books.google.nl/books?id=frE4BQAAQBAJ)

Comment: This would be really helpful as a  compressing liquid.

Comment: Apparently it is liquid at room temperature.

Comment: Which solid would be compressable at room temperatures.

Comment: It's not. Unless you live in a warm place. Room temperature is $20^\circ~\textrm{C}$.

Comment: The application of this would vary in Tropical countries.where temperatures reach 30 plus degrees.

Comment: Or in a desert.What makes a good alternative.

Comment: Perhaps look up the compressibility of rubidium and potassium.